# Dimension of Component

Tags: pcb, footprint

I need to have a dimensio for a component however i could not be sure about it. I need "x" distance that i mentioned below.

[image]

This is the datasheet drawings;

[image]

In my opinion it should be x=1.3 mm Can you say your consideration? Thank you.

Comment: Interesting to know what this is being used in, given that it is not available for public consumption (seems a bit elitist but not sure if it is a munitions grade function to find north).

Answer (score 2):

X dimension (normally left to right): -

The centre of the connector to a hole on the far left is 10.2 mm (bottom picture). That hole to the hole a bit right of it is 1.4 mm (middle picture) hence, the centre of the connector to the hole dimension you want is 8.8 mm.

And this ties in with the dimension of 17.6mm (gap between the two symmetrical holes) i.e. 8.8 mm x 2 = 17.6 mm.

Y dimension (normally vertical): -

The middle picture shows 0.7 mm vertical to the little hole on the left and the top picture shows 2 mm vertical between that little hole and the two symmetrical holes. Hence the vertical dimension is 1.3 mm.

Answer (score 1):

It's 2mm (Not 2.0? Really?) between the centers of the holes, and 0.7mm from the center of the top hole to the center of the connector. Given those values, 1.3mm from the center of the bottom hole to the center of the connector seems reasonable.